# How do I find out which functions of a shared object are used by a program or an other library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, elf, objdump

How do I find out which functions of a shared object are used by a program or an other library?
In this specific case, I would like to see which functions in /lib/libgcc1_s.so.1 are used by an other dynamic library.
Since they are dynamically linked, objdump -d doesn't resolve the function call addresses.
Is there a way short of running the program in a debugger or relinking statically?
Thanks,

Luca

Edit:

nm and readelf won't do, I don't need to see which symbols are present in a shared object, but which are actually used in an other object that links to it.

Answer (score 49):

**nm** will only work if the library wasn't stripped of its symbols. However, `nm -D` could show you some info:

```
nm -D /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
```

But there's another tool which can help you: **readelf**

> readelf - Displays information about
>   ELF files.

And if you check the man pages, option **-s**: `Displays the entries in symbol table section of the file, if it has one.`

```
readelf -s /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
```

**EDIT:**

Well, symbols that are not implemented inside the object you are inspecting with nm will appear with a **U** flag in front of it, but nm won't tell you which library on your system implements that symbol.

So what you are looking for can probably be achieved with a mixture of **ldd** and **nm**. ldd tells which libraries your application is linked with, and nm tells which symbols are undefined (**U** flag) or implemented locally (**T** flag).

After listing all the undefined symbols (with nm) on the target application, you should iterate through all libraries reported by ldd in search of those symbols (using nm again). If you find the symbol and it's preceded by the T flag, you found it.

By the way, I just wrote this **one-liner for bash** to illustrate my idea. It analyses an application named **win** and tries to find the libraries that implement all the symbols reported as undefined.

```
target="win"; for symbol in $(nm -D $target | grep "U " | cut -b12-); do for library in $(ldd $target | cut -d ' ' -f3- | cut -d' ' -f1); do for lib_symbol in $(nm -D $library | grep "T " | cut -b12-); do if [ $symbol == $lib_symbol ]; then echo "Found symbol: $symbol at [$library]"; fi ; done; done; done;
```

Or, if your terminal supports colors:

```
target="win"; for symbol in $(nm -D $target | grep "U " | cut -b12-); do for library in $(ldd $target | cut -d ' ' -f3- | cut -d' ' -f1); do for lib_symbol in $(nm -D $library | grep "T " | cut -b12-); do if [ $symbol == $lib_symbol ]; then echo -e "Found symbol: \e[1;36m$symbol\033[0m at \e[1;34m$library\033[0m"; fi ; done; done; done;
```

I'm sure someone will find a performance improvement.

Outputs:

```
Found symbol: XCreateColormap at [/usr/lib/libX11.so.6]
Found symbol: XCreateWindow at [/usr/lib/libX11.so.6]
Found symbol: XIfEvent at [/usr/lib/libX11.so.6]
Found symbol: XMapWindow at [/usr/lib/libX11.so.6]
Found symbol: XOpenDisplay at [/usr/lib/libX11.so.6]
Found symbol: __libc_start_main at [/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6]
Found symbol: __stack_chk_fail at [/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6]
Found symbol: glClear at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glClearColor at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glFlush at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXChooseFBConfig at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXChooseVisual at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXCreateContext at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXCreateNewContext at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXCreateWindow at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXGetVisualFromFBConfig at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXMakeContextCurrent at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXMakeCurrent at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
Found symbol: glXQueryVersion at [/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1]
```

Comment: @lultimouomo Updated my answer and added a one-liner for bash to get you started.

Comment: I use `readelf` also with *`-W`* (`Allow output width to exceed 80 characters`).

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/toojays/dffd9b806692a10649c1fcd146ee7866 for a much faster implementation which follows a broadly similar approach.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace)? It intercepts calls to shared library functions at runtime and prints information about them as they occur.

Since this is a dynamic solution, it wouldn't print any information for a library call made in part of your program that never gets executed. But it might still be helpful depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of one, even `nm` is of limited use for what you seem to intend. Also, preloading (of the GNU linker) could invalidate any assumptions you make after using a tool that purportedly could do that. See the [ld.so man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so). `LD_PRELOAD` can be used by anyone to override the resolution of symbols as it would occur under normal circumstances.

However, even without a debugger you can use `LD_DEBUG` to see which function ultimately is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `nm` tool can help you since it displays the symbols' names contained in a binary file.
It is as simple as ABC to use:

```
nm my_binary
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using technique called static analysis in Reverse Engineering

You need a Disassembler for this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler

IDA PRO is a good disassembler witch answers your question.It is capable of reading ELF file format but unfortunately it is not free.

Comment: Every seasoned reverse engineer will be very picky about what (and how much) to analyze. What you suggest would require a *comprehensive* analysis. It's done for some pieces of software, but it's rare because it's a lot of work. Static analysis is a bad advice for what the asker wants to achieve.